# Getting areas, length of sides and neighborhood of Voronoi cells in Python

Tags: python, geometry

In the Mathematica Stack Exchange there is [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20646/finding-the-perimeter-area-and-number-of-sides-of-a-voronoi-cell) question about finding the area, perimeter and number of sides of Voronoi cells. I want to know if there is any library in Python that allows one to, given a square and `N` points inside it, get the areas, the length of each side and the neighborhoods of all Voronoi cells in the Voronoi diagram generated by the points. By neighborhood of a cell, I mean a list of which cells share a side with it.